# while buidling a project with CMAKE, I got "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c++, cmake, physics, macos-sierra

I'm building a big project related to a simulation of a detector in physics.

I have to compile the project using CMAKE on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 and my processor architecture is 64-bits.

I built all the requirement programs using "homebrew".

I tried to compile in different CMAKE architecture modes:

```
cmake ../mu3e

cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 ../mu3e

cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=i386 ../mu3e

cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="ppc;i386" ../mu3e

cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64;i386" ../mu3e
```

../mu3e is the directory of the source.

I always ended up with the same or similar error regarding the ***"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"*** and ***"ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"***:

```
[ 66%] Built target mu3eAnaFibreTrackStat
[ 66%] Building CXX object mu3eAna/Fibres/CMakeFiles/mu3eAnaFibreAna.dir/fibreana.cpp.o
[ 67%] Linking CXX shared library libmu3eAnaFibreAna.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "HitStatistics::processFrame(std::__1::map<unsigned int, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::hit_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::hit_t> >, std::__1::less<unsigned int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<unsigned int const, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::hit_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::hit_t> > > > >*)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::processFrame() in fibreana.cpp.o
  "HitStatistics::HitStatistics(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::setHitStat(bool) in fibreana.cpp.o
  "TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_fibreana.cpp in fibreana.cpp.o
  "MPPCStatistics::processFrame(std::__1::map<unsigned int, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::sensor_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::sensor_t> >, std::__1::less<unsigned int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<unsigned int const, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::sensor_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::sensor_t> > > > >*)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::processFrame() in fibreana.cpp.o
  "MPPCStatistics::MPPCStatistics(unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::setMPPCStat(bool) in fibreana.cpp.o
  "FibreStatistics::processFrame(std::__1::map<unsigned int, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::fibre_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::fibre_t> >, std::__1::less<unsigned int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<unsigned int const, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::fibre_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::fibre_t> > > > >*)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::processFrame() in fibreana.cpp.o
  "FibreStatistics::FibreStatistics(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::setFibreStat(bool) in fibreana.cpp.o
  "TrackStatistics::processFrame(std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::track_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::track_t> >*, std::__1::map<unsigned int, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::hit_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::hit_t> >, std::__1::less<unsigned int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<unsigned int const, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::hit_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::hit_t> > > > >*)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::processFrame() in fibreana.cpp.o
  "TrackStatistics::TrackStatistics()", referenced from:
      fibreAna::setTrackStat(bool) in fibreana.cpp.o
  "FibreEndStatistics::processFrame(std::__1::map<unsigned int, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::fibreend_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::fibreend_t> >, std::__1::less<unsigned int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<unsigned int const, std::__1::vector<fibreAnaTypes::fibreend_t, std::__1::allocator<fibreAnaTypes::fibreend_t> > > > >*)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::processFrame() in fibreana.cpp.o
  "FibreEndStatistics::FibreEndStatistics(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::setFibreEndStat(bool) in fibreana.cpp.o
  "TChain::TChain(char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::fibreAna(char const*) in fibreana.cpp.o
  "TClass::GetClass(std::type_info const&, bool, bool)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::init() in fibreana.cpp.o
  "TObject::operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::fibreAna(char const*) in fibreana.cpp.o
  "TStorage::ObjectAlloc(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::fibreAna(char const*) in fibreana.cpp.o
  "TDataType::GetType(std::type_info const&)", referenced from:
      fibreAna::init() in fibreana.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [mu3eAna/Fibres/libmu3eAnaFibreAna.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [mu3eAna/Fibres/CMakeFiles/mu3eAnaFibreAna.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When compiling in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, everything works correctly, which might give you a hint why this is not working.

Thank you for any possible advice and please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: You need to re-run cmake configurations file in another directory, with the correct architecture. Shared library with .dylib are only for ios, if I am not making a mistake here

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it was not so very clear what you meant. At the same time, my question has very little information. I was able to solved part of the problem. Apparently I had to make SHARED library STATICS.
but my project was not fully compiled, since I have new errors at further percentage, at least, that's progress XD
Thank you very much for your time.